# Number of receiving queues is double the number of cores of my server?

Tags: linux, kernel, nic, mellanox

I'm using Mellanox ConnectX-5 100 GB NIC, Linux kernel 5.15 and my server has 32 cores (SMT disabled). But in the /sys/net//queues, the number of rx queues is 64, which is double the number of cores of my server? How to fix it

Comment: is hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: no, it was disabled. In case it is enabled, i will have 64 virtual cores and the number of rx queues is 128. I suppose it is because of AF_XDP.